# PLEASE help - I changed to a new server and I'm not able to access the Admin panel on the old server

Tags: redirect

I have an old version of the Magento shopping cart (1.3.1) running on an older VPS server and I installed a new version of the Magento shopping cart 1.9.1 to a new Cloud server. The domain was resolving to the old shopping cart while I added products to the new shopping cart via an IP address (it was like an IP/~hostingACCOUNTuserID/index.php/ ) That worked fine. I was able to access the new Admin panel by going to IP/~hostingACCOUNTuserID/index.php/admin. Everything was working. Then - last night - I changed the nameservers to point my domain to the new Cloud server. I tested it to make sure that I was able to connect to the OLD ADMIN panel via that IP address also because my orders are in there! But now - all of a sudden - if I go to the old Admin panel via the IP address like this:

http://216.134.5.73/~makeup/index.php/admin

It loads the OLD Admin panel login page, I fill out my user name and password and click to LOGIN and then it REDIRECTS to the front page of the new site (sort of) - it goes to:

http://www.SAMPLE.com/index.php/admin/index/index/key/9febaa223a83422cef87787e773956fe/?SID=eea007535157f5d05c944274011c90d5

(www.SAMPLE.com is already resolving to the new Cloud server).

Can you please help me resolve this? I'm really desperate - I need to get to my orders...

Thank you,

Allysin

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like what you need to do is setup a hosts override to point your domain back to the old IP address.

Usually in /etc/hosts on Linux machines or windows/system32/drivers/hosts ( may be worth checking )

Set it by using the old IP followed by the host name both with and without www if needed.

Alternatively, access the database table core_config_data where it will set the domain for the website address to point to a host name or IP like you can reach the old server on and serve the domain content.

Comment: Hi John, Thank you for helping! I did already change the core_config_data in the database (I've put in the correct IP address like this: http://216.134.5.73/~makeup/index.php but it did not seem to help. Anything else you think I could try? Thank you so very much, Allysin

Comment: This should work! So if it isn't, you should probably also flush all caches